# Рендеринг роутов в зависимости от состояния

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Второй день бьюсь с роутингом и не могу исправить ошибку, надеюсь на вашу помощь)

***Суть проблемы:*** При изменении состояния `isMusicEnabled` (`ParameterHook`) из другого компонента (`ConfirmationPage`) при помощи контекста (`ParameterContext`) в `routes` не поступает новое значение и соответственно рендерится только `ConfirmationPage`.

В других приложениях использовал подобную конструкцию для авторизации - всё работало, а вот сейчас ни в какую (установка значения `isMusicEnabled` точно работает, проверял через `useEffect` в хуке, в `routes` же `useEffect` не реагирует на изменения, другие состояния в хуке и контексте работают корректно).

Зависимости:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "serve": "^13.0.2",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1"
}
```

App:

```
export default () => {
    let routes = useRoutes();

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            { /*...*/ }
            <ParameterProvider>
                { routes }
            </ParameterProvider>
            { /*...*/ }
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
```

routes:

```
export const useRoutes = () => {
    const { isMusicEnabled } = useParameter();

    if(isMusicEnabled === undefined)
        return (
            <Routes>
                <Route path="*" element={ <ConfirmationPage/> }/>
            </Routes>
        );

    return (
        <>
            { /* ... */ }
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={ <HomePage/> } exact/>
                <Route path="/:category" element={ <CategoryPage/> } exact/>
                <Route path="/:category/:id" element={ <CategoryPage/> } exact/>
                <Route path="*" element={ <HomePage/> }/>
            </Routes>
            { /* ... */ }
        </>
    );
};
```

ParameterHook:

```
export const ParameterHook = () => {
    /* ... */
    const [isMusicEnabled, setMusicEnabled] = useState(undefined);

    useEffect(() => {
        /* ... */
        setMusicEnabled(localStorage.getItem("music"));
    }, []);

    /**
     * Переключает состояние музыки на сайте.
     * <b>Внимание!</b> Для установки конкретного значения необходимо инвертировать его.
     */
    const changeMusicState = useCallback((state = isMusicEnabled) => {
        localStorage.setItem("music", !state);
        setMusicEnabled(!state);
    }, [isMusicEnabled]);

    return { isMusicEnabled, changeMusicState };
}
```

ParameterContext:

```
const ParameterContext = createContext({ });

export const useParameter = () => {
    return useContext(ParameterContext);
}

export const ParameterProvider = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <ParameterContext.Provider value={{ ...ParameterHook() }}>
            { children }
        </ParameterContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

ConfirmationPage:

```
export default () => {
    const { changeMusicState } = useParameter();

    return (
        <section className="confirmation">
            { /* ... */ }
            <div className="buttons">
                <button onClick={ () => changeMusicState(false) }>Да!</button>
                <button onClick={ () => changeMusicState(true) }>Не нужно.</button>
            </div>
            { /* ... */ }
        </section>
    )
}
```